# RemoveNodeStateAsync() on a node in fabric cluster fails even when the node is in disabled state.

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a custom auto scale set up for scaling of nodes in my cluster. Scale up works great. I have issues with scaling down. The problem is when I want to scale down, I identify the node that I want to remove- after that I call DeactivateNodeAsync() method on that with the intent of removing the node. I wait till deactivation is done, I check the status of the node to confirm it is disabled. Once it is disbled I call the method RemoveNodeStateAsync() so that cluster can register that this node is being removed.

But my problem is - when I call RemoveNodeStateAsync(), I am getting the following exception - which says that the node is up. This is the complete exception.

> Scale Containers: Scale Nodes Failed . Exception :
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> 
>   System.Fabric.FabricException: Node is up. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80071BC4    at
>   System.Fabric.Interop.NativeClient.IFabricClusterManagementClient9.EndNodeStateRemoved(IFabricAsyncOperationContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.b__0(IFabricAsyncOperationContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Fabric.Interop.AsyncCallOutAdapter2`1.Finish(IFabricAsyncOperationContext
>   context, Boolean expectedCompletedSynchronously)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)

What am I missing ? Why is it saying that the node is up even after explicitly checking the status which says node is disabled ? How can I register to the cluster that some node is removed. Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this azure article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-programmatic-scaling

RemoveNodeState needs to be done after the node is removed from the ScaleSet not before.